# so i am making a website but with the same code on 2 html files the output is not the same

Tags: html, css

So i am making a website and i wanted to go from the home page to a sub page. That all works. But the top bar isnt the same anymore. I duplicated all code from the home file to the sub page. But it still doesnt work. I've tried so many things i even have rewritten my entire code but it still doesn't work.

This is the code for my topbar it is the exact same in both files, i copy and pasten it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>StanPlayzz Dev's</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Images/YTlogo.png">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topbar" style="height: 23px;">
            <img class="banner" src="Images/YTBanner.png" height="23" width="47">
            <a class="active" href="index.html"><span class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size: 17px;">home</span>Home</a>
            <a href="assetstore.html"><span class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:17px;">shopping_cart</span>Asset Store</a>
            <a href="about.html"><span class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size: 17px;">feed</span>About</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*But it still [doesn't] work.*" - what does that mean, what does it do instead of "working"? How is it not working? Are there any errors? Are the resources loading, are the paths correct?

Comment: Send both code entierly

Comment: it still doesnt work means the top bar still doesnt display the correct size. the code is exact same for both html files i duped the files. but they give a different output

Comment: ill explain the problem simple. i have 2 pages. i want them to have the same topbar. but with the exact same code the bar isn't the same. I am sorry if i'm confusing you.

Comment: @StanPlayzz We really need to see all your code of both pages, or else we are just randomly guessing what could be going on. Here's my guess: Did you link the same stylesheet file to both pages? Did you copy the `<head>` tag as well, or only the `<body>` content?

Comment: i have the html file and i just duped that, renamed the file and thats it. however the output is not the same as the original one

Comment: i cant seem to type the other code. its to many characters. but its the exact same. you know what. i will put my whole project in a google drive

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p2ANq468YxzzfYq9BuxT1yEKHtgsepdP?usp=sharing) this is my project

Comment: @StanPlayzz In 'assetstore.html' change `<div class="topbar" style="height: 23px;">` to `<div class="topbar">` or simply remove the height property of your topbar ;)

Comment: ye i added the height to see if it would fix my problem. sadly thats not it. do you see the problem im talking about when u open the file in chrome?

Comment: I don't see it. Both pages look exactly the same after I removed the height property from the topbar. This caused a tiny scrollbar to appear on the right of the screen, shifting the elements a bit. Apart from this, everything looks the same.

Comment: hmmm the bar at the assetstore seem to be thinner at my screen

Comment: this is weird... i downloaded the one from drive and now they are both thin. they should be kinda thick you know...

Comment: i added a screenshot so u can see how it is on my screen on my original file

Comment: oh- my- god... i am so emberassed... the code was never wrong... i was zoomed in... Dear everyone thank you really much for your time... i feel so bad lol

Comment: Haha well, that happened to me before. Glad you figured it out. Have a good one :)